# Error System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, javascriptserializer

I want to create dynamic expressions for my web services to allow client applications to pass dynamic queries to filter the data as they require. To this end I'm trying to serialize / deserialize an **Expression** in C# / .NET. that the client application can pass into my web service. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error when I attempt to deserialize the expression.

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[[System.Func`2[[Common.Entities.ModuleEntityAdmins, Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
```

The classes I am deserializing contain parameterless constructors and are decorated with the appropriate *[DataContract]* and *[DataMember]* attributes.

```
[DataContract]
public class ModuleEntityAdmins
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<ModuleEntityAdmin> Modules { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ModuleEntityAdmins()
    {
        this.Modules = new List<ModuleEntityAdmin>();
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class ModuleEntityAdmin
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ModuleEntityAdmin()
    {
    }
}
```

I create a simple **Expression** to return a single instance of the class.

```
Expression<Func<ModuleEntityAdmins, ModuleEntityAdmin>> expr1 = m => m.Modules.Find(q => q.Id == 1);
```

I serialize the **Expression** using the following function.

```
public string SerializeObject(object objtoserialize)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objtoserialize);
}
```

At this point everythng is fine.

I then go to deserialize the string using the following function.

```
public T DeserializeObject<T>(string jsonObject)
{
    T result = default(T);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonObject))
    {
        //errors on the line below!!
        result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(jsonObject);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It is when attempting to deserialize the **Expression** that I get the error.

I have correctly decorated the classes involved and they both have parameterless constructors so can't understand why I am getting the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: expression trees don't serialize worth a damn; they have a `ToString()` which gives a representation of the lambda, and that is probably what `JsonConvert` is outputting, but: there is zero chance of deserializing an expression tree trivially; it *just doesn't work like that*

Comment: FWIW: I can't even run your serialize code (copy pasting everything from the question); I get "Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'ManifestModule' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'. Path 'Body.Method.Module.Assembly'."

Comment: to be clear: the error isn't telling you that `ModuleEntityAdmin` or `ModuleEntityAdmins` is lacking a particular constructor; it is telling you that the *expression types* are missing it.

Comment: There are various libraries to serialize expression trees, like [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Remote.Linq/) and [this one](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq)

Comment: What Marc said.. But just FYI it's not your classes without the parameterless constructor, it's `Expression<Func<, >>`. Unrelated, but I find it weird that you mix `JsonConvert` and `JavascriptSerializer`. The latter is "obsolete" - - not officially, but per MS' own docs. [man I type slow, refreshed and ya'll be me to it]

Comment: I only took the approack of Expressions after reading other posts on here that suggested that it was a good approach for for creating dynamic queries that could be serialized / deserialized. Maybe there are other better approaches?

Comment: I'm using JavascriptSerializer as it provides suppot for large files (I've removed that code for clarity). We have web services that send images which can be large in size and other serializers don't work.

Comment: @canton7 neat, I wonder how those deal with closures/displayclasses turned into ConstantExpressions... specifically on deserialize. I'm sure there a bunch of edge cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is exists simple labrary Remote.Linq - https://github.com/6bee/Remote.Linq

You can try example code:

```
            Expression<Func<ModuleEntityAdmins, ModuleEntityAdmin>> expr1 = m => m.Modules.Find(q => q.Id == 1);

            var remoteExpression = expr1.ToRemoteLinqExpression();

            var s = SerializeObject(new RequestExp { Expression = expr1 });

            RequestExp requestExp = DeserializeObject< RequestExp > (s);

            Expression<Func<ModuleEntityAdmins, ModuleEntityAdmin>> expression = requestExp.Expression.ToLinqExpression<ModuleEntityAdmins, ModuleEntityAdmin>();
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the RequestExp type. Is this part of Remote.Linq?